# Testing Matrix inequalities

Tags: matrix, algebraic-manipulation, inequalities

I was wondering how one might check whether matrix inequalities are true/false the same way it can be done for scalar variables (like in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56304/is-there-a-way-to-check-inequalities-in-mathematica-given-restrictions)).

Say I want to test the obvious inequality

> A,B are positive definite dxd matrices.
> Prove that Tr(A B)>=0

I would do something like

```
conditions = {A 
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[VectorGreater]\), 
TemplateBox[{"2"},
"SemidefiniteConeList"]]\) 0 , B 
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[VectorGreater]\), 
TemplateBox[{"2"},
"SemidefiniteConeList"]]\) 0 , (A | B) \[Element] 
 Matrices[{d, d}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]}

Simplify[Reduce[
  Flatten[{Tr[A.B] >= 0, conditions}], {A, B}], conditions]
```

But `Reduce` doesn't seem able to resolve matrix domains. How can such inequalities be tested?

Comment: Don't try to use such fancy notation, Express your problem in normal Mathematical code.

Comment: What do you mean by notation? The variable `condition` is just the code needed to impose positive definiteness on the matrices. I know it looks ugly, but it's just a translation of the mathematical problem above.